# How to create an array of a custom class

Tags: java

I am a bit new to Java and coding in general and I came across a problem that so far I can't solve. 
The functionality is: A switch menu which asks for input to be saved on an array (option 1) and then with the second option the attributes of the objects in the array be printed.

I have a custom class:

Course

```
 public class Course {


    String name_course;
    String code_course;
    int credits_course;

    Course(String name, String code, int credits){

        this.name_course = name;
        this.code_course = code;
        this.credits_course = credits;

    }
}
```

In another file I have defined a function for the input of the user be saved on the array and also the function to loop over the array and print the values.

```
public class Logic{


    static BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    static PrintStream out = System.out;


    //I believe this function does not save correctly the input on the array 
    static Course[] course = new Course[6];

    public static void register_course(String name, String code, int credits) {

        for (int i = 0; i < course.length; i++) {
            course[i] = new Course(name, code, credits);



        }

   // This only prints one value as the previous function is likely wrong 
   public static void print_course(Course[] pcourse) {


        for (int i = 0; i < course.length; i++) {
            out.println(course[i]);

        }


    }
}
```

Here is the switch I have on the main

```
 // Just to clarify I have a do while loop that loops over the switch but I won't include it, it works fine 
 public static void process_option(int pOption) throws IOException{
        switch(pOption){

            case 1:
                out.println("Name");
                String name = in.readLine();
                out.println("Code");
                String code = in.readLine();
                out.println("Credits");
                int credits = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
                Logic.register_course(name, code, credits);


                break;

            case 2:
                Logic.print_course(Logic.course);

                break;

    }
```

I would really appreciate any help to figure out my error.
Thanks.

Comment: if you are just starting out, you can always use lists, more specific arraylists. They are going to make your life *a lot* easier. [Overview here](https://www.callicoder.com/java-arraylist/)

Comment: I believe you're not having a code problem but a logic problem (though some might consider them the same thing). Take a step back and re-think through what you have to do, write it out in words even as a step by step process, then convert that outline to code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I print my Java object without getting "SomeType@2f92e0f4"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4)

Comment: The parameter for the `print` method is called `pcourse` but you end up printing the static one `course` parameter - I believe you need to either rename the parameter (to `course`) or print the array passed as parameter  - named `pcourse` (instead of the staticly defined) - ie. change it to: `out.println(pcourse[i]);`

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stack overflow, I think you made your code a bit more complicated than needed the class `Logic` is not really needed. But less start from the class `Course` here is my version

```
public class Course {
    private String nameCourse;
    private String codeCourse;
    private int creditsCourse = 0;


   public void nameCourse(String name){
     this.nameCourse = name;
   }

   public void codeCourse(String name){
     this.codeCourse = name.toUpperCase();
   }


   public void creditsCourse(int credits){
     this.creditsCourse = credits;
   }


   @Override
   public String toString(){
       return "Course " + this.nameCourse + " with code " +  this.codeCourse + " credit for the course " + this.creditsCourse;
   }

}
```

it does exactly the same work of your but it uses setter instead of the constructor method have a look at this [Setter](https://www.codejava.net/coding/java-getter-and-setter-tutorial-from-basics-to-best-practices). I also used the `@Override` annotation to override the standard toString() method of the [Object class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html).
Now to your implementation of the control the main problem with your `Logic` class is that you are limited to just 6 courses what if you need more 
Luckily for us, Java has [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) that can handle a dynamically sized array of any class
Here is my example code

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Course> courses = new ArrayList<>();
    Course course;
    for (int counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++) {
        course = new Course();
        course.codeCourse("cs" + counter);
        course.nameCourse("Computer Science " + counter);
        course.creditsCourse(10 + counter);
        courses.add(course);
    }

    for (Course c : courses) {
        System.out.println(c.toString());
    }

}
```

you can see the declaration `ArrayList<Course> courses = new ArrayList<>()` and the add to the list of the new course `courses.add(course)` and finally `System.out.println(c.toString())` to print the content of the object as string.

The output looks like

```
Course Computer Science 0 with code CS0 credit for the course 10
Course Computer Science 1 with code CS1 credit for the course 11
Course Computer Science 2 with code CS2 credit for the course 12
Course Computer Science 3 with code CS3 credit for the course 13
Course Computer Science 4 with code CS4 credit for the course 14
Course Computer Science 5 with code CS5 credit for the course 15
Course Computer Science 6 with code CS6 credit for the course 16
Course Computer Science 7 with code CS7 credit for the course 17
Course Computer Science 8 with code CS8 credit for the course 18
Course Computer Science 9 with code CS9 credit for the course 19
```

I think you get the idea hopefully this has been useful have fun with Java